# SSIS package not importing into SS2008 due to dots in the name

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm importing an SSIS package into SQL Server 2008 Integration Services . The package name contains dots and I'm getting this error message:

> The package name, What.No.Dots,
>   contains characters that are not
>   valid. The following characters are
>   not valid:  \ / : . * ? " < > | [ ] =
>   Parameter name: What.No.Dots
>   (MsDtsSrvr)

[image]

Is this really the case with SQL Server 2008? I could import packages with dots in the name into SQL Server 2005. I know this sounds like a dumb question, but I  want to  double check before I rename **all my SSIS packages** (I like dots).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Books online has this to say about migrating DTS packages:
"In some cases, such as when the package name contains invalid characters (/ \ : [ ] . =), or when the package contains unregistered objects, the Package Migration Wizard cannot perform the migration until these issues are resolved."

So yeah it looks like they do not want you to use . in your name.